# Using SELECT IF to recode one date from four variables in SPSS

Tags: date, spss

Self-taught at SPSS here. Need to know the appropriate syntax to recode four DATE variables into one, based on which would be the latest date. I have four DATE variables in a dataset with 165 cases:

```
wnd_heal_date
wnd_heal_d14_date
wnd_heal_d30_date
wnd_heal_3m_date
```

And each variable may or may not contain a value for each case. I want to recode a new variable which scans the dates from all four and only selects the one that is the latest and puts it into a new variable (x_final_wound_heal_date).

How to use the SELECT IF function for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select if` function selects rows in the data, and so is not appropriate for this case. What you can do is this instead:

```
compute x_final_wound_heal_date = 
    max(wnd_heal_date, wnd_heal_d14_date, wnd_heal_d30_date, wnd_heal_3m_date).
VARIABLE LABELS   x_final_wnd_heal_date 'Time to definitive wound healing (days)'. 
VARIABLE LEVEL   x_final_wnd_heal_date(SCALE). 
ALTER TYPE x_final_wnd_heal_date(DATE11).
```

This will put the latest of available date values in the new variable.

Comment: That worked great. I just had to add the DATE format to the syntax for the variable to display the data correctly.

  
`COMPUTE x_final_wnd_heal_date=MAX(wnd_heal_date,wnd_heal_d14_date,wnd_heal_d30_date,wnd_heal_3m_date).`

`VARIABLE LABELS   x_final_wnd_heal_date 'Time to definitive wound healing (days)'.`

`VARIABLE LEVEL   x_final_wnd_heal_date(SCALE).`

`ALTER TYPE x_final_wnd_heal_date(DATE11).`